# python shutil.make_archive - compress without nested directory structure

Tags: python, shutil

I've searched and found a few different answers, read the docs (which aren't the most helpful), and toggled around with my code but still can't seem to find the answer I'm looking for.

I'd like to archive everything in my download_dir, leaf files only, into a zip|tar but every solution I try also includes the parent tree of `tmp/stuff/downloads` - is it possible to do this with `shutil.make_archive`? Or will I have to roll my own with zipfile/tarfile?

```py
def download_file(file_name):
   # download to /tmp/stuff/downloads/file_name

download_file('file1.txt')
download_file('hello.md')

shutil.make_archive(root_dir='/tmp/stuff/downloads', 
                    base_dir='/tmp/stuff/downloads', 
                    base_name='my_file', format='zip')

# I want `my_file.zip` to only contain file1.txt and hello.md, no nested directories
```

Comment: Looking at the documentation, there are not a option to do what you want. You can try use zipfile https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html

Comment: I figured that could be the case.. was just hoping for a cleaner solution to handle different formats